# smallest element in a subset of integer

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers

I'm really struggling with the notion that the existence of an injection from an infinite set into N, automatically prove that there exists a bijection between the two.
As far as i could find, it's related to the fact that any subset of N has a smallest element.

How can any non recursively enumerable subset of N have a smallest element ? What would that element be ?  What about subset of N for which there might be some undecidability involved ? (Like in : given a bijection between N and all programs in language L , for a subset of all programs that terminate, what is the smallest integer reached through the bijection ? )

Comment: If there is an injection $\varphi$ from the infinite set  $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, map the smallest element of $\varphi(A)$ to $1$, the second smallest to $2$, and so on. Computability is a separate issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, if mapping each of the successive smallest elements, was indeed possible (ie : if there existed an algorithm to do so ) ? The fact that there are known situation where there exists some subset, that provably admits no algorithm ( the subset of integer associated to non terminating programs is one) does pose a question, doesn't it ?  Wasn't algorithms that can exists precisely an abstraction of an ideal mathematician's work at some point (like in godel arguments) ?

Comment: You appear to identify existence with computability. That is a not unreasonable point of view, but not the standard one.

Comment: The thing is, that it seems that the very reason why computability and existence diverged, is because computability was discovered later. Before that, it seemed obvious that any subset of N would be recursivly enumerable. So it became a foundation. But there was not real reason for that, as the truth is that not all subset of N are recursively enumerable. Somehow the view sticked. And we've got "uncountable" infinite. Whereas it seems that all this is only a consequences of the recursive enumerability / non recursive enumerability.